# Finding round intervals in a range

Tags: python, algorithm, matplotlib, rounding

Drawing programs such as `matplotlib`, find `n` round intervals for the plot axis. For instance, if x is in the range of `0.05 - 0.9`, the round numbers in the axis are `0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0`.

My question is: what is the logic for such algorithm (I do not need the code, it can be in any programming language)?

We have a range and need to find `n` round intervals within *when we do not know the precision for rounding OR if n intervals can give round values.*

***My thought:***

1. Find the closet round value within x% (acceptable padding of the plot) above and below the range.
2. Set `n` (say between 4-8) to have round intervals between the min and max.

If it is a practical approach to do so, I still have no idea how to manage the algorithm for either step.

Comment: This really depends on what you consider acceptable for the numbers on the axis. For example, are the numbers `0, 0.35, 0.7, 1.05, ...` acceptable? How about not starting from zero, e.g. `103, 117, 131, 145`? Before you can even think about an algorithm, you need to fully specify what you want the outputs to be in all situations. Hint: a typical axis notation uses multiples of 1, 2 or 5.

Comment: @user3386109 programs like `matplotlib` use common norms, for example, 5% space before and after the plot. No, there is no need to start from 0, as the range can be 90-99. However, all plotting programs tend to use the most round numbers. So, your numbers usually tend to be `0, 0.3, 0.6, 0.9`.

Comment: @user3386109 anyway, it doesn't matter what I exactly want. I have no clue how to start. Therefore, even a basic raw outcome is enough for me to code.

Comment: [matplotlib's method](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/ticker.py#L1873) (if not this function, probably in this file)

Comment: Can you make the motivation clearer? Is this about academically understanding theory of tick locations? Is this about understanding which algorithm matplotlib uses, i.e. do you want someone to explain the matplotlib code to you? Do you simply want to get some locator for your project (in which case you can directly use the matplotlib one)?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest the purpose is not plotting, but I need round intervals for another set of calculations involving numpy arrays.

Comment: @jedwards very helpful link. The function does the job in part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If interested in how tickers generally work, you may look into http://vis.stanford.edu/papers/tick-labels and references therein. 
An implementation of that algorithm is available [here](https://github.com/quantenschaum/ctplot/blob/master/ctplot/ticks.py).

Matplotlib uses a slightly different way, which can of course be directly be taken from the `MaxNLocator` in the 
 [matplotlib source code](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/6ec80eac66c4828f28540f76734cae811787d626/lib/matplotlib/ticker.py#L1760).

You may use this matplotlib locator for just any purpose you like (or reimplement the respective part yourself).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker

loc = mticker.MaxNLocator(nbins=10, min_n_ticks=3)

arr = np.array([23, 21, 27])
ticks = loc.tick_values(arr.min(), arr.max())
print(ticks)
### [21.  21.6 22.2 22.8 23.4 24.  24.6 25.2 25.8 26.4 27. ]

arr = np.array([.5, .3, .9])
ticks = loc.tick_values(arr.min(), arr.max())
print(ticks)
### [0.24 0.32 0.4  0.48 0.56 0.64 0.72 0.8  0.88 0.96]

# or use less target bins:
loc2 = mticker.MaxNLocator(nbins=5, min_n_ticks=3)
arr = np.array([.5, .3, .9])
ticks = loc2.tick_values(arr.min(), arr.max())
print(ticks)
### [0.3  0.45 0.6  0.75 0.9 ]
```